Netplan multiple NICS with VLAN config
I want to create 2 nic on a Ubuntu 22.04 server with the following requirements:
ens160:

Attachted to port group with vlan id 123 in esx
Fixed IP 192.168.123.26/24
Used for internet connection with DFGW 192.168.123.254

ens224:

Attached to port group with vlan id 4095 (=trunk) in esx
Vlan 121:

IP 192.168.121.210/24
No access to other subnets


Vlan 124

IP 192.168.124.26/24
No access to other subnets



So far I've created the following netplan config:
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.123.26/24
      nameservers:
        search:
          - company.com
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.123.254
    ens224:
      dhcp4: false
  vlans:
    vlan.121:
      id: 121
      link: ens224
      addresses:
        - 192.168.121.210/24
    vlan.124:
      id: 124
      link: ens224
      addresses:
        - 192.168.124.26/24
  version: 2

Output of ip route
default via 192.168.123.254 dev ens160 proto static
172.17.0.0/16 dev dockero proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-05ea9776e316 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 
172.23.0.0/16 dev br-3716096f315a proto kernel scope link src 172.23.0.1 
192.168.121.0/24 dev vlan.121 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.121.210 
192.168.123.0/24 dev ens160 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.123.26 
192.168.124.0/24 dev vlan. 124 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.124.26 

and route

What is working with this config:

internet access via interface ens160
access to vlan 121 & 124 via internet IP
Ping to the 3 IP-addresses of the server

What is not working:

External access to this server via 1 of the IP's (e.g. ssh access, webserver...)
nmap does show however that the ports in question (e.g. 22, 80) are open but no connection can be established
to illustrate: output of curl command

`
curl -LIsak 192.168.123.26:443 -vvv
*   Trying 192.168.123.26:443...
* Connected to 192.168.123.26 (192.168.123.26) port 443
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.123.26:443
> User-Agent: curl/8.8.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Request completely sent off

So in short:
Outgoing traffic seem to work but incoming not (eventhough ens160 has not been changed).
What do I need to alter to my netplan.yaml in order to achieve my requirements?
